# preventDefault doesn't take effect in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input named shop_cat_edit and the code as below. But in FireFox this code never works... Even IE feels ok with it. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('[name=shop_cat_edit]').on('click',function(e){
   $('#shop_cat_selector_form').on('submit', function(){e.preventDefault();}); 
});
```

Comment: Can you please paste your html code too? or create a fiddle.

Comment: There is no `e` in the nested function. You are only preventing the outer one.

Comment: Ok, then what should i do to prevent default action of a clicked btn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `e` is not declared in the function you use it

```
function(){             <-- no function param for event is set here
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

It should look like this

```
  function(e){e.preventDefault();}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner .on event can be moved outside, then add e as its parameter.

Comment: Could u plz give an example?